# How to get white color when on dark theme and dark color when on light theme?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

In my app, I specified a light and dark theme. I want to create a button that is white on dark theme and black on light theme. Is there a way to get those colors conditionally like `Theme.of(context).somethingHere`?

```dart
class _MainState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Cart(),
      builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const IntroPage(),
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried `Theme.of(context).cardColor`, `Theme.of(context).highlightColor` and many other, but some of them work with light theme, some with dark theme, but none of them looked good with both themes. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, check for [`Theme.of(context).brightness`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/brightness.html) and adjust the button color conditionally:

```dart
final brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
...
final isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

Example usage:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

In a ThemeData(), you can specify a lot of parameters like buttons style.

For example, on darkmode, if you want to give a green color and a specific shape to all the OutlinedButtons of your app, simply do :

```
...
darkTheme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[800],
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
...
```

You can also give specific params to your light mode. This way, the style of your widgets apply everywhere in your app, unless you give a specific style to an element of your code.

Reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html